# How to separate Monday-Friday from Saturday and Sunday Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on project that has data like this (I use pandas framework with python):

```
days     rain

0          1
2          0
3          1
1          0
6          1
2          1
1          1
2          1
3          0
4          0
5          0
```

Days 0-6 is Monday-Sunday and rain 0 is no rain day and rain 1 is raining day.

I want to separate the days into these new column Monday-Friday, Saturday, Sunday with the data in that row is 1 if it is that day and 0 if it is not that day and the index need to be the same as the original file. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Monday-Friday'] = df['days'].isin(range(5)).astype(int)
df['Saturday'] = (df['days'] == 5).astype(int)
df['Sunday'] = (df['days'] == 6).astype(int)
```